# security "InvalidArgumentException in AccessDecisionManager.php line 52": The strategy "affirmative" is not supported

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks

I have upload my first symfony project on https://www.olympe.in/.

So, I have a blank page.

When I use **app_dev.php** I have this issue :

> ```
> InvalidArgumentException in
> ```
>
> /dns/in/olympe/loicg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager.php
>
> line 52: The strategy "affirmative" is not supported.
>
> ```
> in AccessDecisionManager.php line 52
> at AccessDecisionManager->__construct(array(object(RoleHierarchyVoter),
> ```
>
> object(ExpressionVoter), object(AuthenticatedVoter)), 'affirmative',
>   false, true) in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3456
>       at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_Access_DecisionManagerService()
>   in bootstrap.php.cache line 2097
>       at Container->get('security.access.decision_manager') in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1933
>       at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_AuthorizationCheckerService()
>   in bootstrap.php.cache line 2097
>       at Container->get('security.authorization_checker') in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1946
>       at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_ContextService() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2097
>       at Container->get('security.context', '2') in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3103
>       at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getTwigService() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2097
>       at Container->get('twig') in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 316
>       at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getAssetic_AssetManagerService() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2097
>       at Container->get('assetic.asset_manager') in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1902
>       at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getRouting_LoaderService() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2097
>       at Container->get('routing.loader') in Router.php line 54
>       at Router->getRouteCollection() in Router.php line 344
>       at Router->getMatcherDumperInstance() in Router.php line 267
>       at Router->getMatcher() in Router.php line 233
>       at Router->matchRequest(object(Request)) in RouterListener.php line 125
>       at RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
>       at call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request',
>   object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) in WrappedListener.php line 59
>       at WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
>       at call_user_func(object(WrappedListener), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request',
>   object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher)) in EventDispatcher.php line 164
>       at EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener),
>   object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
>   in EventDispatcher.php line 53
>       at EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php line
>   167
>       at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 112
>       at TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent)) in bootstrap.php.cache line 3009
>       at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in bootstrap.php.cache line 2982
>       at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in bootstrap.php.cache line 3131
>       at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in bootstrap.php.cache line 2376
>       at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 21

Notice: I have remove the cache before.

This is the prod.log:

```
[2015-01-12 20:11:12] request.INFO: Matched route "home" (parameters: "_controller": "AppBundle\Controller\IndexController::indexAction", "_route": "home") [] []
[2015-01-12 20:11:12] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "The strategy "affirmative" is not supported." at /dns/in/olympe/loicg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager.php line 52 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The strategy \"affirmative\" is not supported. at /dns/in/olympe/loicg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager.php:52)"} []
[2015-01-12 20:11:12] request.CRITICAL: Exception thrown when handling an exception (InvalidArgumentException: The strategy "affirmative" is not supported.) {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The strategy \"affirmative\" is not supported. at /dns/in/olympe/loicg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager.php:52)"} []
```

I have enable php error reporting and everything seem to be ok.

security.yml:

```
#    security:
#        providers:
#            in_memory:
#                memory: ~

#        firewalls:
#            dev:
#                pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
#                security: false

#            default:
#                anonymous: ~
```

Comment: Have you enabled error display? Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: I comment all lines in security.yml, and my page work ! But ... is a solution ?

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the content of the `security.yml` file in your question?